# "selected" attribute in drop-down menu in meteor template not working

Tags: html, meteor, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a problem with a drop-down list in a meteor template; it's a little esoteric, but would appreciate some help with the following:

```html
<template name="TeamsLeftDropDown">
  <select class="teamsLeftDropDown" name="">
    <option disabled selected="selected">Pick this week's team</option>
    {{#each teamsLeft}}
      <option value={{.}}>{{.}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
  <input type="button" name="quickChoiceButton" value="Submit">
</template>
```

The drop-down consists of a `disabled` and `selected` option, followed by a list of options based on a simple array `teamsLeft`. When the page loads, the `disabled/selected` option is on top, as it should be. So far so good.

When the button is clicked, the selected team is sent off to the database and the `teamsLeft` array is filtered to remove the chosen team - and the template automatically re-renders *(praise be to Meteor)* and the drop-down options are just as they should be.

**BUT** Now the drop-down behaves as if the first team in the `teamsLeft` array is `selected` (say, "Team A") - rather than the `pick this week's team` option (even though it's still there, above with `selected` and `disabled` attributes).

Sorry for such a long and niche question, but if anyone has any ideas why this is happening, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Just remove disabled attribute from first option, also you need to re-select first option via JavaScript  after page is re-rendered. To avoid any action on first option set the value to something what will be filtered in your script, for example to "false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that when the page first loads, the disabled option is all that is in your select tag because the addition of the options from your "teamsLeft" variable have not been rendered yet.  Thus, the disabled option gets selected by default.  When you select an option after everything has been rendered, that option becomes the selected option.  Then, when you click the "Submit" button and the database is updated, the options from "teamsLeft" get re-rendered.  When this happens, the options are quickly removed from the DOM and re-added.  During this intermediate state when the options have been remove, the disabled option is all that is left in the DOM.  However, since it is disabled, the browser doesn't make it the selected option.  When the "teamsLeft" options are added back into the DOM, the browser selects the first one that gets added because it is not disabled.

To fix this, you can do either of the following (the first being much easier and the preferred way):

1) Remove the "disabled" attribute from your first option and validate in your submit function that the user has not selected this option.

2) In your submit function (perhaps right after you do the database update), set up a [Tracker.afterFlush](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush) that will select your first option after things have been re-rendered. One possible implementation of this looks as follows:

```
Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
  jQuery(".teamsLeftDropDown option:first").prop("selected",true);  
});
```

Comment: Thank you @jswett33 for your clear explanation and solution. I will take option1 as you suggest.

That said, it's quite irksome that on the first template render, the disabled option gets selected by default, but not on the second render - this seems odd. But not worth losing any more time over - thanks for your help